# 2014 points inside a cube

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

> $2014$ points are chosen inside a cube with side $13$. Can a cube with
>   side $1$ be found inside it so that it doesn't contain any of chosen
>   points?

This must be a problem solved using pigeonhole principle, however I still can't see a clever way to start.

Comment: The first step is to compute $13 \times 13 \times 13$. Let us know when you've done that.

Comment: @TonyK: though $12 \times 12 \times 12$ (the number of lattice points strictly inside the cube) is rather smaller, so the problem may not be quite that easy

Comment: @Henry: Yes, if you count a point on the boundary of a cube as being 'contained' in that cube, then it's not so simple.